# Microsoft Report Viewer Drillthrough using Multiple Data Sources

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer2008

The error I'm getting is "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'AssetLatencyCompleteDataSet_fsAssetLatencyComplete'"

I have 2 Data Sources, AssetSummaryDataSet and AssetLatencyCompleteDataSet

I can only select 1 Data instance, I've looked around and it appears that I should be able to add additional data sources for a single report and they would populate within the report viewer control seen here. [image]

I have created the DrillThrough handler, however I still get the above error.

How can I add the data source instance I'm missing to the report viewer?

```
{
public partial class frmAssetSummaryRpt : Form
{
    public frmAssetSummaryRpt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmAssetSummaryRpt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'assetSummaryDataSet.fsAssetRecoverySummaryByClientWO' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.fsAssetRecoverySummaryByClientWOTableAdapter.Fill(this.assetSummaryDataSet.fsAssetRecoverySummaryByClientWO);


        reportViewer1.Drillthrough += new DrillthroughEventHandler(reportDrillthroughEventHandler);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


    }
    void reportDrillthroughEventHandler(object sender, DrillthroughEventArgs e)
    {

        LocalReport localReport = (LocalReport)e.Report;
        localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("fsAssetLatencyComplete", (object)assetLatencyCompleteDataSet.fsAssetLatencyComplete));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAssetLatencyFullRpt AssetLatencyFullReport = new frmAssetLatencyFullRpt();
        AssetLatencyFullReport.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change only following line

```
localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("fsAssetLatencyComplete", (object)assetLatencyCompleteDataSet.fsAssetLatencyComplete));
```

Instead of "fsAssetLatencyComplete" specify "AssetLatencyCompleteDataSet_fsAssetLatencyComplete"